# How to always show the first attribute on the node?

Tags: neo4j

I'm experimenting  with the neo4j [webadmin](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tools-webadmin.html). I found the [online demo console](http://www.neo4j.org/learn/try) had a [Game of Thrones](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Game_of_Thrones_Wiki) Graph structure.. (really, it should have been Song of Ice and Fire.. but oh well)

I wanted to make some changes and play with the graph so I took the code from the demo console and added it to my local neo4j server.. I wanted to visualize the structure in my webadmin's data browser with all nodes having their respective named attributes in them instead of just a node number.

I added a new style (which, for some reason, disappears every time I close the browser) with `{name}` for label, but obviously, the house nodes have attributes `house` instead of `names` so the house nodes have N/A on them.

If I can put `{id}` on a label and see the node id's.. there must be something to show the first attribute.. no?

---

This is the custom style:

[image: Custom style]

And the graph that it produces:

[image: Graph]

Finally, the nodes on console:
[image: nodes on console]

<sup>(Ignore the nodes above 60, they are not related to GOT)</sup>

As you can see, some nodes have `names` and some have `house` - is there a way to display whatever it is on the node?

Comment: @ulkas, thanks you. I did try ``{name,house}``.. and it does work.. but I was interested in displaying attributes for unknown nodes.. eg., I just want to display all nodes, and I don't what attributes it may have..

Comment: i don't know about the option for first property, but this might be a close one: {props|truncate:10}. {props} for all properties and truncate to get at least a part of the property

Comment: when you get it working, a screen cast would be appreciated, there is too few docs on this. We could host it at neo4j.org.

Comment: @ulkas can you make a real answer out of your helpful tips! Something else to note: if you choose an icon, make sure to change the label color to black :)

Comment: btw. cool that you liked our GoT dataset, feel free to improve it, would love to see a large one that pulls in data from one of the GoT wikis

Comment: @ulkas - how did you find out you could use ``props`` and ``truncate`` on there? is there a list of things I can probably use there somewhere on the internet or is it cypher query?

Comment: i dont remember, but there is some help icon around the input fields + some sort of syntax trying on blind.

Answer (score 0):

clicking on node it displays the options to change the color , size and caption in the bottom. For the caption displays with tow option called id and yours first attribute name. so there u can change as per yours wish.

Comment: What about a little more illustration? Screenshot? add the link and we will edit to make it appear. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .